# vb.net (1.10) in percentage

Tags: vb.net, percentage

i am creating an small application which allows user to calculate sale price by cost price * 10% (profit for example) and result will store in sale price

```
dim saleprice as integer
costprice = textbox1.text
percent = textbox2.text
saleprice = costprice * percent
label1.text = saleprice
```

but the problem is when user input 10 in textbox2.text it will multiply by 100 if user input 1.10 then result will be correct but i want to skip this "1." so user will directly put 10 or  whatever but i dont know how to do that please help and thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour], and add `Option Strict On` to the top of all your code files...always

Answer (score 1):

There is a main issue with your code, but also a couple of smaller issues.

The main issue is that you have defined saleprice as an integer, so it can only hold integers. I'm guessing that you also have `costprice` and `percent` defined as integers. Instead, define them all as `Single` or `Double`.

There is also the issue of converting types. The information you enter into the TextBox is stored as a string. In the real world you would have to make sure that the `.Text` property is convertable to a numeric value and then convert it. With your current Visual Studio settings, the conversion is done behind the scenes. This makes life easier for beginners, but encourages very sloppy programming.

I would suggest changing your compiler settings so that `Option Strict` is on ,`Option Explicit` is on, `Option Compare` is set to Binary and `Option Infer` is off.

This will make writing your code a little harder, but in the long run, it will save you time and force you to write better code.

**Edit :** Whoops

I missed the crucial part of your question - to do away with the "1" part and just enter the percent as a whole number - this should be your code

So.. in its simplest and still error prone form, your code would need to be ..

```
Dim costprice As Double
Dim percent As Double
Dim saleprice As Double
costprice = Val(TextBox1.Text)
percent = Val(textbox2.text)/100
saleprice = costprice * (1 + percent)
Label1.Text = saleprice.ToString
```

To increase the cost by 10 percent, simply enter 10 in the Percent textbox. To decrease the cost by 10 percent, enter -10.

Comment: onc again david thank you very much for your help this works for me :)